# Search string inside an array (in_array)

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array and I am trying to search for the word 'sport' within the array.  My array only works if my array only contains the word 'Sport', but if more than one item is in my array it echos the incorrect text.  Any suggestions please, my array looks like this:
Array ( [0] => Sport, News )

```
if (in_array('Sport', $names)) {
    echo "Got ya";
}
else
{

  echo "na";
}
```

Comment: Its bizarre that your array looks like that, I would expect to see News as the second element in the array. If that was the case, you can simply use `array_search`, which will return false if not found, or the index number if found, which would be 0 in this case. Note that 0 !== false

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the issue lies with the array. Create an array like show below and it should work

```
$names[]='Sport';
$names[]='News';
```

Add On:

To add to your response to get the rows accordingly it should be something like:

```
$query="select name from table";
$result=mysqli_query($database_connection,$query);
if($result){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $names[]=$row['name'];
        }
    }else{
        echo "No results found";
    }
}else{
  echo "Unable to perform request"; //Make sure you have a valid query
}
```

This will produce an array named $names from a database where you have a table named `table` (stupid thing to do but it's just for an example) and a column named `name`;

Comment: TY, but I am not sure why I am not calling my data back from my database correctly?  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_request)) {
  $names[]= array( $row['tags']);
}